# Passing a list of shell commands to GNU parallel

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel

I have a list of shell commands stored as strings in variable prog and currently I executing them in parallel via

```
for I in 1 10; do 
  eval "${prog[$I]}"& 
done
wait
```

How would one achieve the same result with GNU parallel? I tried piping seq 1 10 via

```
parallel ::: seq 1 10 | { read -d '' x; eval "${prog[$x]}"; }
```

but I could not even get above to work wo parallel ::: so clearly I am doing it wrong.

One a side note I managed to get the following to run

```
parallel ::: $(  for i in {1..2}; do eval ${prog[$i]}; done )
```

but it is not doing so in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
parallel ::: "${prog[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not completely satisfactory I ended up with the following solution:

```
arg1="5"
arg2="some option"

run_parallel(){
  some_executable $1 $2 $3
}
export -f run_parallel

seq 1 50|
   parallel --pipe -N1 --jobs 10 'read I; run_parallel $I '"$arg1"' '"$arg2"';'
```

I am not completely satisfied because I have just found out I can not use progress bar along with --pipe and I don't know how to do this with pipe. So in case anyone knows please let me know. Also I could not figure out a way to do it without combining double and single quites as above so that also looks a bit weird. When I run this through shell check it says for instance

```
(info): Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
```

Nevertheless it works and produces the expected result with correct arguments into the executable so still it is a solution (and it avoids using eval as I was trying previously so that is some bonus points).